# url management in Yii 2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have this url

```
http://example.com/index.php/controller_name/action_name?queryString=123
```

This url is working fine but when I am trying to use the queryString like in the old version of Yii

```
http://example.com/index.php/controller_name/action_name/queryString/123
```

I get an **"unable to solve request"** error.

I 've already enable prettyurl in my config file and the following url is working

```
 http://example.com/index.php/controller_name/action_name.
```

My config looks like :

```
'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            'module/<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
        ],
    ],
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately this feature didn't migrate to Yii2, you can still define such rules manually

```
'books/view/queryString/<queryString:\w+>' => 'books/view',
```

[Link on github with this issue](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/2047)

> Because of many client API and Oauth servers don't work without encode

[Sam Dark answer](http://yiiframework.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=18429&start=10)

Comment: Alex have you any idea if is this planned to be implemented in the future?

Comment: I am trying to get the same can you pl see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73578796/6854117)?