# Yii2 create user friendly URL with parameters

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Hi I've to create user friendly URL but when using with parameters it's not working.

**Url:**

```
Url::to(['site/index', 'id' => 1]);
```

**url looks like :**

```
localhost/testApplication/frontend/web/index.php/site/index?id=1
```

**/forntend/config/main.php**

```
'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        //'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [

        ],
    ],
```

I want a output like

```
localhost/testApplication/frontend/web/index.php/site/index/id/1
```

and after that how to access id value in controller.

Comment: Do you want this for `site/index` only?

Comment: yes it's only for site/index

Comment: possible duplicate of [url management in Yii 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22963353/url-management-in-yii-2)

Answer (score 1):

```
'rules' => [
  'site/index/id/<id:\d+>' => 'site/index'
  //'site/index/<id:\d+>' => 'site/index' Better solution
  //'<controller>/<action>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>' Will be applied for all controllers and actions
],
```

[Routing Doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#url-rules).

And after in your action :

```
public function actionIndex($id)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: how can write a rule for more than one parameters?

Comment: `Url::to(['site/index', 'id' => 1, 'param2' => 'test']);`

//

`'site/index/<id:\d+>/<param2>' => 'site/index'`

//

`public function actionIndex($id, $param2)`

Comment: is any rule like site/index/*=>site/index

Comment: I am trying to get the same can you pl see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73578796/6854117)?

Answer (score 0):

Is really strange, for me using the parameter 'id' always show errors, I needed to change the parameter to 'user_id', but in other parts of the code I could use, really don't know why, but try to rename the parameter.